# Spring Security: Unable to re-login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am fixing an existing application, where first login works fine and the logout works fine taking me back to login page.
However after logout, when I try to re-login ***without browser refresh*** (just enter credentials on login page), I am getting redirected to Host based URL(which is blocked over the intranet).

Reason
`SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);`
is null during re-login.
I think that may be because I loggedOut, session is cleared by LogoutHandler.

Code for reference.

```
`public class BroadleafAdminAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();        
private static final String successUrlParameter = "successUrl=";
private static final String APPLICATIONURL = "APPLICATIONURL";

@Resource(name = "blAdminSecurityRemoteService")
protected SecurityVerifier adminRemoteSecurityService;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
    AdminUser user = adminRemoteSecurityService.getPersistentAdminUser();
    if (user != null && user.getLastUsedSandBoxId() != null) {
        request.getSession(false).setAttribute(BroadleafSandBoxResolver.SANDBOX_ID_VAR, user.getLastUsedSandBoxId());
    }
    
    SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
   if (savedRequest == null) {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        return;
    }
 .
 String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
 .
  *Logic where I update my targetUrl* 
 .
 getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
}`
```

I want to avoid going into this condition
`if (savedRequest == null)` Since I am then unable to execute
`*Logic where I update my targetUrl*`

Comment: Hi there, please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please paste some source code and/or configuration details.

Comment: Why not use `cookie` to save the targetUrl. Write targetUrl to cookie when first login success. When session is cleared while login again,  you can go into condition `if (savedRequest == null)`  and read targetUrl from cookie. Forgive my poor english.